# R installation through conda runs into error

Tags: r, conda

I am installing R through conda as follows on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
v=3.6.0
conda create -n env-r${v} -c r r=${v} r-ggplot2 r-gridExtra r-gtable r-tidyr r-devtools
conda activate env-r${v}
```

That runs ok. **It installs 3.6.1 instead of 3.6.0.** And then when I use R, for example, installing a package not on conda;

```
Rscript -e 'install.packages("label.switching", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")'
```

I get this error:

```
Error in path.expand(new) : object 'lb' not found
Calls: .First ... .libPaths -> Sys.glob -> path.expand -> path.expand
Execution halted
```

If I open R and run stuff in it, there are more errors:

```
Error in path.expand(new) : object 'lb' not found
Calls: .First ... .libPaths -> Sys.glob -> path.expand -> path.expand
Execution halted
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
```

Running conda 4.7.5.

Ran `sessionInfo()` inside R.

```
>> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/roy/miniconda3/envs/env-r3.6.0/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.6.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

Comment: Try installing `r-base=3.6.0` or `r-essentials=3.6.0` from the default channels, instead of `-c r r=3.6.0`.

Comment: That helps with the conda installation, but the error 'object 'lb' not found' remains. Ran a normal installation without conda and still get the same error. Probably an R-3.6.1 issue and nothing to do with conda.

Comment: Do you have an [Rprofile](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup) that refers to `lb`?

Comment: Ooooh yes! It was a old custom setting in the Rprofile.